# Selenium with BrowserMob-Proxy

Tags: java, maven, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I started to write some test on Selenium and thought it would be great if I could get the performance metrics for example upon logging in to our website. I came across BrowserMob-Proxy. I started by copying the first five line from Lightbody's github page and I already got the error message: "ProxyServer cannot be resolved to a type" and "Proxy cannot be resolved to a type".

Can somebody please tell me what is still missing here?

Here's the pom.xml:

```
...
</plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- 20131112 ab hier neu hinzugefügt von "https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Drone" -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-webdriver-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian.drone}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- bis hier -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-selenium</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-selenium-server</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api-2.5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
        <artifactId>browsermob-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST_VERSION (ex: 2.0-beta-9)</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
                <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
        <dependencies>
...
```

And here's the class where I'm trying to make the methods 'start' and 'end' ('start' isn't complete yet and I haven't made 'end'...). By calling 'start' BrowserMob should start measuring the performance and by 'end' it should stop measuring...

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class Timer {

public void start() {

    // start the proxy
    ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(4444);
    server.start();

    // get the Selenium proxy object
    Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();

    // configure it as a desired capability
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

    // start the browser up
    WebDriver driver;

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies with the version line. It looks like you copy and pasted directly from the browsermob github page. Instead, the line should look like this.

```
<version>2.0-beta-9</version>
```

Drop LATEST_VERSION and the other syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try BrowserMobProxyServer server = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
And then get regular proxy out of it.
And yes, get latest version.